# What does 'ccp' signify in Cocos2d/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I keep seeing a phrase like this:

```
//Example one
CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(-1000, 0);

//Another Example
// 3) Determine relative movement speeds for space dust and background
CGPoint dustSpeed = ccp(0.1, 0.1);
CGPoint bgSpeed = ccp(0.05, 0.05);
```

So what does ccp signify? Is it a property of CCParallax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like Stephen said, it's just a macro for CGPointMake(x, y), but if you particularly mean what does "ccp" stand for it's most likely **c** o **c** os2d **p** oint

Answer (score 8):

Are you using Cocos2D? If so, ccp is just a C macro to create a point. As in:

```
#define ccp(__X__,__Y__) CGPointMake(__X__,__Y__)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a convenience constructor for the CGPoint type.

Pretty sure it's just a macro to CGPointMake, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shorthand macro that maps to CGPointMake(x, y).

Basically it's a way to create CGPoints with less typing.

Answer (score 1):

Nope no difference except CGPointMake is harder to type:

```
#define     ccp(__X__, __Y__)   CGPointMake(__X__,__Y__)
```

Found here:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.3/_c_g_point_extension_8h_source.html